# To display object properties based on its ID

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have component called `list` in which i will display all my `customers list` as in below image:

[image]

and selecting particular customer i will emit that customer **id** and i will display that **id** in another component called `display`:

[image]

Instead of displaying the `customer id` how can i display that **id's** properties(for ex name, email )like this:

[image]

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-pwlfet?file=src/app/display/display.component.html)**

Comment: I have added forked solution on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-bntmaw

Comment: I know that i can i emit the whole `object`, If i emit the whole object in some component i want subscribe only the `id`, How can i subscribe the `id` by emitting the full object in `display` component.@TheParam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing ID only, pass the full object on click event like this -

```
(click)="selected($event, customer)"
```

and display whatever you want to show like this -

```
{{CustId?.id}} {{CustId?.name}}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-5n7fne?file=src/app/list/list.component.html)

Comment: I want pass only id for the functionalities.

Comment: instead of passing you can use only `id` as per requirement, isn't it?

Comment: Ya correct, Using only id i should display the properties.

Comment: is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: If i pass `full object` how i can get only id from the `object`?? Because i want the `full object` in one `component `and only `id` in another `component`.

Comment: @Shankar for that please check my attached example, you only need to iterate over the object to get name and id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187841/discussion-between-shankar-and-pardeep-jain).

Comment: If i emit a full `customer` object, How i subscribe only the `id` from the emitted `customer` object?

Comment: Now i am emitting the id and subscribing the id like this: **(value => {
      this.CustId = value;**
    })

Comment: @Shankar As you are an emitting object (As per my suggestion), now you are subscribing to object not to ID.

Comment: I know that now i am subscribing the `object` not the id, But in some component i want subscribe the Only `id` how can i `subscribe` the id?? by emitting the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187846/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-shankar).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Angular Material, the following example shows how to display the property you want for the options in the dropdown, and for the selected value, outside of the dropdown.
It uses value binding on `mat-select` to bind the selected customer to `selectedCustomer`:

```
const customers = [
  { id: 2, email: 'test1@cust.com', name: 'Jack' },
  { id: 2, email: 'test2@cust.com', name: 'John' }
];

<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Customer" [(value)]="selectedCustomer">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">
        {{ customer.id }}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>{{ selectedCustomer.name }} {{ selectedCustomer.email }}</p>
```

Comment: I know that i can i emit the whole `object`, If i emit the whole object in some component i want subscribe only the `id`, How can i subscribe the `id` by emitting the full object in `display` component.